# split text file based on varying row separator

Tags: java

I've one text file. Given below is an example of a file.

```
CN=100
adshnxhndxghdngfhdsfs
dsjfxnudshxf hfgdsh
ldnf jsdbf hdsbf


CN=200
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe

XN=300
jskhd sa
jd jhgdsxbfgsdhbfgeh
kdsnbdhfhdgfhdbfhd
CN=400
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe

XN=500
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe
```

I want to split this file into different files on the basis of row separator. But in my file only = is constant as a row separator. Using etl I've tried using row separator as = and got different files but those were not a expected output and performance issue were there because I had to read files multiple time to get filtered data even though that output didnt match the exact requirement.

I'm not a java developer, but I need small assistance on this. I want my expected out in multiple files from one single file given above like this

```
File one

CN=100
adshnxhndxghdngfhdsfs
dsjfxnudshxf hfgdsh
ldnf jsdbf hdsbf


File two

CN=200
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe


File three

XN=300
jskhd sa
jd jhgdsxbfgsdhbfgeh
kdsnbdhfhdgfhdbfhd


File four

CN=400
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe


File five

XN=500
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe
```

Can I have any suggestion please so that I could perform this activity using java ? Because I think using java all process can be done at one time while reading the file. And then may I can try your suggestion in etl tool as well.

What I have tried:

In etl I was using "=" as a row separator and receiving the split files on the basis of that. So My split files in out comes were like these:

```
------
File one

CN
---------------
file two

100
adshnxhndxghdngfhdsfs
dsjfxnudshxf hfgdsh
ldnf jsdbf hdsbf


CN
------------------------
file three

200
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe

XN
----------------------
file four

300
jskhd sa
jd jhgdsxbfgsdhbfgeh
kdsnbdhfhdgfhdbfhd
CN
-----------------------
file five

400
jhnxrhewxrgewhgxew
ejxn jehwbf ewhfbew
jdksfn sbfhb hfe

XN
-------------------------------
```

I'm recieving kind of these files and again using etl after doing some adding files back to the characters which came into different files. So Its like reading files again and again and even not getting the exact expecting output affecting performance.

This what I figured out from internet to process my file

```
private String currentFile = "root.txt";

public static final String REGEX = "^\w+=\d+";

public void foo() throws Exception{

  Path path = Paths.get("path/to/your/input/file.txt");
  Files.lines(path).forEach(line -> {
    if(line.matches(REGEX)) {
      //Extract the digit and update currentFile
      currentFile = "File DOC_ID_"+line.substring(3, line.length())+".txt";
      System.out.println("Current file is now : currentFile);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Writing this line to "+currentFile + " :" + line);
      //Files.write(...);
    }
  });
```

Please share your inputs and then I will try to take ahead from there.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Since you don’t show what you have tried. Reading/Writing a file is a fairly straight forward process and lots of help on how to do that. While reading the file, check for lines with “=” and start a new file. It’s difficult to help without seeing what you have tried.

Comment: @JohnG, Hi John..I've updated the question in my best possible manner. Now could you please have a look ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems ok. You just need to add a file writer. Since the "writer" needs to be passed on to the code inside a "closure", I made the writer as a member to the class.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class FileTest {
  public String currentFile="";
  public BufferedWriter writer=null;
  public final String REGEX = "^\\s*\\w+=\\d+\\s*$";

  public void test() {
    try {
      Files.lines(Paths.get("root.txt")).forEach(line -> {
        try {
          if (line.matches(REGEX)) {
            currentFile = "File_DOC_ID_"+line.substring(3, line.length())+".txt";
            System.out.println("Current file is now : " + currentFile);
            if (writer!=null) writer.close(); writer=null;
            writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(currentFile));
            if (writer==null) System.out.println("Failed to open file!\n");

          } else {
            System.out.println("Writing this line to "+currentFile + " :" + line);
            writer.write(line);
          }
        }
        catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}
      });
    }
    catch(Exception e) { System.out.println(e);}
  }
}

class FileTester {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    FileTest ft=new FileTest(); ft.test();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi...I have tried using your code like this http://prnt.sc/d3dosz but am getting error like this http://prnt.sc/d3dovv  Any idea why its happening ?

Comment: As far as possible, please try to add feedback as a comment (or as info to your original question). Outside links to images tend to expire (get deleted by image hosting servers), thus leaving the current discussion fragmented. The errors you showed are compilation errors. I added the imports to the code. If you get compilation errors (such as missing symbols), you can search for them in oracle/java api/docs (or just search in google).

Answer (score 1):

I would break things up to make it easier. Think of things that you are going to be doing often while reading the file... Each time you read a line you may have to simply write a regular line to the current file OR you have reached the start of a new file to make i.e… when you get to a line with “=”. Starting from the point of having to start a new file you will have to save/close the current file, parse the string to get the file name for the new file, create a new file using the name from the parsed line, then continue reading the file until you reach the next “=” or end of the file. Below is psuedo code for one possible way to beak this up to make it easier.

Edit - change to not create a file for every line :(

```
data = open file to read
read data to get the first “=” to get the first file name
ParseStringToGetFileName
While not data EOF 
   curWriteFile = GetNewFile to write to with supplied file name
   while readline does not equal “=” OR EOF
     read the next line
     write to curWriteFile 
   end while
   SaveClose write file
   If not EOF
      ParseStringToGetFileName
End while not EOF
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To make life a little easier your file names could be what is provided within the so called row separator (ie: **CN=100.txt**, **CN=200.txt**, etc). By looking at your sample file contents and as you said, the Row Separator line contains an equals (**=**) character which is apparently typical for the data file you're processing.

The sample method code I have provided below assumes that the equals (**=**) character will **always** reside as the *third* character within the Row Separator line. The file names saved to disk within the provided destination folder path are actually the text contained on that very same Row Separator line.

If the supplied destination folder path does not exist then it is automatically created.

The code that does all the required processing of the supplied Main Data File runs within a separate Thread so that other work can continue within your application while the file processing runs in the background (console output always displays what is going on).

Data which contains the very same Row Separator text is appended to a file of that name unless of course the file doesn't exist yet in which case it is automatically created.

Data related to each Row Separator is separated from previous Row Separator line block entries by way of a blank line for easier reading.

Here is the **processFileData()** method:

```
private static void processFileData(String dataFilePath, String destinationFolderPath) {
    // Establish a new Thread for processing file data...
    Thread dataProcessingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Keep things running until this thread is Interrupted
            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                BufferedReader br = null;
                try {
                    // Does Data file exist
                    File file = new File(dataFilePath);
                    if (!file.exists()) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR - Main Data File Not Found!\n\n" 
                                         + dataFilePath);
                        return;
                    }   
                    // Does Destination Folder path exist?
                    // If not then create the path.
                    file = new File(destinationFolderPath);
                    if (!file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) { file.mkdirs(); }   

                    //Read in the Main Data File...
                    String srcFileLine = null;
                    String sep = System.getProperty("line.separator");

                    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFilePath));
                    while((srcFileLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                        if (!srcFileLine.trim().equals("")) {
                            // Is an = character detected in the third position
                            // of the read in string?
                            if (srcFileLine.substring(2, 3).equals("=")) {
                                // Yes, this must be the Row Separator line so
                                // let's use it to create our file name.
                                String curFile = srcFileLine.trim() + ".txt";
                                // Apply the file name to the provided destination folder path.
                                String fileName = destinationFolderPath + "/" + curFile;
                                // Display the file name currently being processed.
                                System.out.println("\nProcessing File: --> " + curFile);
                                // Write the Row Separator line to its respective file
                                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(fileName, true);
                                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer);
                                bw.write(srcFileLine.trim() + sep);
                                // Continue reading the Main Data File to acquire
                                // the data lines related to the Row Separator
                                while ((srcFileLine = br.readLine()) != null && !srcFileLine.equals("") && 
                                                                  !srcFileLine.substring(2, 3).equals("=")){
                                    // Display the current line being saved to file
                                    System.out.println("Writing this line to " + curFile + " : " + srcFileLine);
                                    // Write the current line to file.
                                    bw.write(srcFileLine.trim() + sep);
                                }
                                // Add a blank line to the file indicating the end of block
                                bw.write("" + sep);
                                // Close the file currently being written to.
                                bw.close(); writer.close();
                            }
                        }   
                    }
                    // Close the Main Data File reader.
                    br.close();
                } 
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); } 
                catch (IOException ex) { System.out.println(ex.getMessage()); } 
                // Kill this processing thread
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });

    // Start the File data Processing but only if it isn't 
    // already doing so.
    if (!dataProcessingThread.isAlive()) { dataProcessingThread.start(); }
}
```

And here is how you might use the above method:

```
processFileData("C:/CompanyData/MainDataFile.txt", C:/CompanyData/ProcessedData");
```

That's it...

Comment: Thanks for this code. I dont know how..but when I used your code first time it gave me exact all split files I was looking for but after that some time it give 3 sometimes 1 sometimes one file having no data. Is there anything needs to be fixed ?